# How to send and receive data for JS games?

Tags: javascript, html, post

When I'm on an html based website I can send POST and GET requests how do I do the equivalent in a JS game? One of the most popular games may be agar.io. So if we use that as an example - How are details about my game state (position, size, etc) being sent to the server and how is my browser receiving information about other player's game states? Where can I see this information? When I inspect the page under the network tab in google chrome as I normally do to view GET and POST requests there's no activity for agar.io game play.

Answer (score 1):

For GET and POST requests:

It could only get info at the moment from the server, and could never be real-time. Thus it would nearly be impossible to view your friends' game status unless you are sending ajax requests with an interval in a number of seconds.

**HOWEVER**, loading ajax every 2 seconds, let's say, will result in a big load on the server. Unless you have a server network which could handle hundreds of requests simultaneously, otherwise you are strongly adviced not to use this method.

Well, then, how to have real-time communications with your friends?

1. WebRTC

It is a technology developed by Google in 2013. Search on the web for more information on how to make good use of it to develop real-time communications.
Sadly this one is only supported by mainly mozilla and webkit browsers.

2. Push APIs

There are a lot of APIs regarding push notifications. A typical example using this will be Facebook, which receive messages real-time, or immediately after message being sent.